# Bizarre artifacting when baking diffuse selected to active

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, shaders, baking

Getting this bizarre artifacting across my UV while trying to bake this candy cane spiral texture to them. I've used selected to active in the past to bake textures from existing meshes and it worked fine but with this specific model it's exploding for some reason. Any idea for what I could try to get it to project correctly? I've tried many different extrusion distances and ray cast distances.

[image: Pair of legs with candy cane pattern]

Comment: Pleas indicate  what your 'Selected' and 'Active' objects are.. it's a little confusing? I may not be getting it, but you're baking pure red?

Comment: I'm trying to bake the white spiral onto the red. The white spiral is selected and I'm baking to the active red.